# Is this supposed to be a suffix , infix or prefix rule?

Tags: spacy

I want to add special case for tokenizing the following

`DATE:01/01/2020`

The default tokenization keeps this as a single token, but I need to split its like this

`'DATE', ':', '01/01/2020'`

I added an infix rule to the default as follows which seems to work

```
# modify tokenizer infix patterns
infixes = (
    LIST_ELLIPSES
    + LIST_ICONS
    + [
        r"(?<=[0-9])[+\-\*^](?=[0-9-])",
        r"(?<=[{al}{q}])\.(?=[{au}{q}])".format(
            al=ALPHA_LOWER, au=ALPHA_UPPER, q=CONCAT_QUOTES
        ),
        r"(?<=[{a}]),(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
        r"(?<=[{a}])(?:{h})(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA, h=HYPHENS),
        r"(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=/](?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),

        #this regex is added to handle colon preceded by alpha and followed by numeric
        r"(?<=[{a}])[:](?=([0-9][0-9][/]))".format(a=ALPHA)
    ]
)

infix_re = compile_infix_regex(infixes)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_re.finditer
doc = nlp(text)
print([t.text for t in doc])
```

However I was wondering which one I am supposed to add it to - suffix, infix, or prefix?

I could not come up with a suffix rule that works.

In general how do we decide which category of rules to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter in the end whether a token was a prefix, infix, or suffix and there can often be multiple ways to get the same result.

I think the best way would be to add a regex that has `:` as an infix between `DATE` and a digit. You could also add both `DATE` and `:` as prefixes instead if this doesn't cause any side effects in other cases, which maybe slightly easier to do because you can just add items to `TOKENIZER_PREFIXES` without writing any regexes.